# Kattis - Stream Lag

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

My code below for the Kattis test - stream lag. I got 7/20 right but I don't know what's wrong and the test fails. The test is [Stream lag](https://open.kattis.com/problems/streamlag).

Can anyone please help me what I'm doing wrong?

```js
var readline = require("readline");

var frames = [];

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

let numberOfFrames;
rl.on("line", function (numberLine) {
  if (numberLine.length == 1) {
    numberOfFrames = parseInt(numberLine);
    return;
  }
  const numbers = numberLine.split(" "); // [1,2]
  frames.push({ sec: numbers[0], seq: numbers[1] });
  frames.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.seq - b.seq;
  });

  if (frames.length == numberOfFrames) {
    console.log(caculateTotalSeconds(frames));
    rl.close();
    process.exit(0);
  }
});

const caculateTotalSeconds = (frames) => {
  let currentSecond = 1;
  let currentDelay = 0;
  frames.forEach((frame, i) => {
    frameSec = parseInt(frame.sec);
    frameSeq = parseInt(frame.seq);

    if (currentSecond < frameSec) {
      currentDelay = currentDelay + (frameSec - currentSecond);
      currentSecond = frameSec + 1;
    } else {
      currentSecond++;
    }
    if (currentSecond < frameSeq) {
      currentDelay = currentDelay + (frameSeq - currentSecond);
      currentSecond = frameSeq + 1;
    }
  });
  return currentDelay;
};
```

Comment: Useful information to [edit] the post to include: (1) describe your strategy (2) did you get a "wrong answer", TLE, runtime error or what? [this is a huge hint of where you went wrong] (3) what test cases do you suppose you might be failing on, or what debugging did you try? See [why is "can someone help me?" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) Thanks.